# Plot data and the mean of each column

Tags: pgfplots

I have a data file which looks like this:

```
1   256
2   197
3   190
4   188
5   219
6   169
7   179
8   181
9   182
10  178
```

where the first column are timesteps and the second column contains the number of iterations an algorithm needed in the corresponding timestep.

I plot this with the first column as the x axis and the second column is the graph. Now I want to add the average amount of iterations over all timesteps and plot it as well.

Is there a way to calculate the mean of a column within `pgfplots` and use this value in the same plot like this:

```
\addplot[samples=2] {\meanValue};
```

Comment: You can use \pgfplotstablegetrowsof and \pgfplotstablegetelem and a \foreach loop to calculate the mean (see \pgfmathparse from the TikZ manual).

Comment: @JohnKormylo I thought of this possibility, but it is mentioned in the manual, that it is quite slow. Also, I hope that there is a more convenient way. But still, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Do you have the data in a csv format?

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent Right now the data is exactly in the format as shown in my post. But it is no problem to delimit it with comma, etc.

Comment: I can not really understand why you want a very simple calculation by means of tough latex codes. Do all your calculations in a spreadsheet, export it to a CSV file and then let LaTeX plot it for you. I do not find it so efficient to ask LaTeX to do calculations too.